# Do references occupy space on stack

Tags: c++, reference

I read that in the following case:

```
int i = 12;
int &a = i;
```

a will not occupy a space on the stack as it is an alias of i;

My question is suppose its a parameter as such

```
void funct(foo& a , int b)
{

}
```

when the function is created will a occupy a space on the stack ?

Comment: Check the assembly output. C++ has nothing to say on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reference is more or less like a pointer at this level and the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo{
     int val;
};

int funct(foo& a, int b)
{
     return a.val;
}

int main(void) {
     foo obj;
     obj.val = 92;
     funct(obj, 22); // 22 is passed by value, obj is passed by reference

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

gets translated to:

```
                .Ltext0:
                    .globl  _Z5functR3fooi  // funct()
                _Z5functR3fooi:
                .LFB2:
                    .cfi_startproc
0000 55             pushq   %rbp  // some stack bookkeeping
                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
                    .cfi_offset 6, -16
0001 4889E5         movq    %rsp, %rbp
                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
0004 48897DF8       movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)   <-- move the address on the stack frame
0008 8975F4         movl    %esi, -12(%rbp)  <-- move the value on the stack frame
000b 488B45F8       movq    -8(%rbp), %rax   <-- get the address from the stack frame
000f 8B00           movl    (%rax), %eax     <-- use it
0011 5D             popq    %rbp
                    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
0012 C3             ret
                    .cfi_endproc
                .LFE2:
                    .globl  main
                main:
                .LFB3:
                    .cfi_startproc // Main
0013 55             pushq   %rbp // Stack bookkeeping
                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
                    .cfi_offset 6, -16
0014 4889E5         movq    %rsp, %rbp
                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
0017 4883EC10       subq    $16, %rsp
                .LBB2:
001b C745F05C       movl    $92, -16(%rbp)     <-- save 92 (the entire POD struct) on the stack frame
     000000
0022 488D45F0       leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax    <-- get the pointer to the stack frame where the obj is
0026 BE160000       movl    $22, %esi          <-- save the value in a register
     00
002b 4889C7         movq    %rax, %rdi         <-- address of the stack frame to the object
002e E8000000       call    _Z5functR3fooi     // funct() call
     00
0033 B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00
                .LBE2:
0038 C9             leave
                    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
0039 C3             ret
                    .cfi_endproc
                .LFE3:
                .Letext0:
```

Of course keep in mind that this is just an implementation (gcc's one to be precise) without any optimization. **It depends on the compiler how this really works**.

(asm generated by http://assembly.ynh.io/)

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard, whether or not a reference requires storage is unspecified. So it depends on the implementation.

A reference is often implemented as an address in assembly. However, a reference is neither a pointer to an object nor a copy of the object. A reference is the object.

Comment: Reading the question more carefully shows that a reference parameter to a function is asked. In that context the caller of the function has to pass `something` to the function but never "the object".

Comment: @harper thanks for the constructive comment it's a nice addition and it really clarifies things up. I didn't mean to give the impression that an object is passed to the function. Nevertheless, a reference parameter to a function (e.g., `foo &a`) is also an alias to the same object (e.g., `i`). As for what is passed in the function (e.g., 'something'), it is completely up to vendor's implementation.